# How to check that List[np.ndarray] contains an np.ndarray?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have an `np.ndarray` and a `list` with several `np.ndarray` elements.
I want to check if my `list` contains concrete `np.ndarray` or not.

I tried to use `in` operator, but got an `ValueError`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.asarray([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = [np.asarray([1, 2, 3]), np.asarray([2, 2, 2])]
>>> a in b  # attempt to check №1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element
is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> any(x == a for x in b)  # attempt to check №2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element
is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I except that there is some way to check `b` contains `a` without changing `a` and `b` types.

Comment: It depends on what you want to check. Particularly, in your code `a != b[0]`. In other words, `a` does not have the same address as the first item in b. If you'd change your code to `b = [a, np.asarray(...)]`, you could use `in`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard function of numpy that is numpy.array_equal(a1, a2)

`for i in b:
     if(numpy.array_equal(a,i)):
         print("found")`

Comment: Yes, I can just `any(np.array_equal(a, i) for i in b)` to compare.